# How do I change the font size on tab and menu

Tags: 14.10, chromium, dpi, scaling

I'm running 14.10 on my MBP with retina display. I scaled the things to 1.5 in the System Settings so everything is good except Chromium.

My chromium looks like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/12Xe2.png

How can I fix this? This is very annoying.